# Como resetar a propriedade DataSource de um DataGridView e não apagar as colunas do Cabeçalho?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou preenchendo meu DataGridView com uma lista de objetos, porém, quando preencho o grid pela primeira vez da tudo certo. Quando seto a propriedade DataSource como nulo, são apagadas as colunas da grid.

Existe a possibilidade de resetar a propriedade DataSource sem apagar as colunas do cabeçalho ?

Trecho de código que utilizo:

```
if (listVetObj.Count > 0)
{
    dgvControle.DataSource = listVetObj;
    dgvControle.Update();
    dgvControle.Refresh();

    txtQtdeLinhas.Text = dgvControle.RowCount.ToString();
    txtQtdeLinhas.Refresh();
}
```

Quando reseto a propriedade dentro de um método são apagadas as colunas do cabeçalho:

Código:

```
private void LimparCampos()
{          
    dgvControle.DataSource = null;
    dgvControle.Update();
    dgvControle.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: As colunas do cabeçalho você cria antes correto ?

Comment: Isso elas são fixas no grid. Quando insiro linha a linha da certo, por questões de perfomance, comecei a usar list e setando direto no DataSource, ai começou esse problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom se pode fazer uma lista vazia pra que ele não desmonte o seu `controle` e permanece com o mesmo `layout`

```
private void LimparCampos()
{          
    dgvControle.DataSource = new List<Class>();
    dgvControle.Update();
    dgvControle.Refresh();
}
```

Onde a `Class` é o nome da sua classe que carrega esse `controle`.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Como associar dados ao controle DataGridView dos Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Propriedade DataGridView.DataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Um detalhe, `new List<T>()` já cria uma lista, não precisa do `ToList()` depois.

Comment: O `ToList` foi proposital, eu não sei o modo que ele envia essa Lista @jbueno fique tranquilo eu sei disso observando a pergunta não sei o modo real que ele utiliza.

Comment: Vou testar desse modo que você passou. E vou fazer o teste com e sem o ToList();

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, fiz da forma que falou e resolveu o problema, porém, como o jbueno comentou fiz sem o ToList(). Obrigado

Comment: Isso @DiegoFarias pode testar das duas maneiras se no seu caso for uma implentação de `IList` `IListSource` `BindList` se não for precisa usar o `ToList` se não nem precisa! eu Coloquei propositalmente.

Comment: @DiegoFarias pronto formatei como você resolveu.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado. Abraço